# Concatenate NPM Script Commands?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I understand that it's possible to chain NPM scripts with `&&`, `pre-` and `post-` hooks, but is it possible to simply separate lengthy script lines into a single, concatenated line?

For example, I'd like to convert this:

```
"script": {
  "build": "--many --commands --are --required --on --a --single --line"
}
```

into this:

```
"script": {
  "part1": "--many --commands",
  "part2": "--are --required",
  "part3": "--on --a",
  "part4": "--single --line",
  "build": "part1 + part2 + part3 + part4"
}
```

So when I enter `npm run build` it will merge all the parts of the command on one line.

I'm also familiar with config variables, but they are not a cross platform solution so I will avoid using them.

Comment: I think the recommended way would be to move it into an external file. A single line Bash file and Batch (or PowerShell) file would be one way, though you would need to "maintain" the two files separately.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it wasn't really possible.  Too bad, but I decided to just setup some Gulp tasks with Node's [**child_pocess.exec**](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A common approach to do it is like:

```
{
  "scripts:": {
    "script1": "cmd1",
    "script2": "cmd2",
    "script3": "cmd3",
    "build": "npm run script1 && npm run script2 && npm run script3",
  }
}
```

Comment: Along with this strategy, one can also use the npm-run-all package for a little cleaner syntax.

Comment: I don't know why this answer has so many upvotes but its completely wrong. The question is asking for **concatenating** not running multiple commands. imagine I want to run "echo  hello world" using 3 scripts with `echo`, `hello` and `world`. `npm run echo && npm run hello && npm run world` is clearly incorrect

Answer (score 3):

You can use the config parameter in your package.json like so,
Although it's longer!

You could reuse your config at least with this method.

There is probably a way to concat multiple environmental variables based on a regex.

```
{

  "config": {
    "part1": "--many --commands",
    "part2": "--are --required",
    "part3": "--on --a",
    "part4": "--single --line",
  },
  "script": {
    "build": "cmd $npm_package_config_part1 $npm_package_config_part2 $npm_package_config_part3 $npm_package_config_part4"
  }
}
```

Comment: The only working solution to this question

Comment: This is brilliant. Can't believe i didn't know this.

Comment: This does not work for `yarn` only for `npm`.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to TheDarkIn1978's answer but shorter:

```
"script": {
  "build:js": "--many --commands",
  "build:css": "--are --required",
  "build:images": "--on --a",
  "build": "run-s build:*"
}
```

Comment: Note, this requires `npm-run-all` package: https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all

Answer (score 2):

You can use npm install -g [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently)

Simple usage :

```
concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg"
```